# Google Map API won't work... (HTML website)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've completed a HTML website on my own domain and everything works fine.

However, when uploading it to my customers domain (a domain that has been newly registered) the Google map doesn't work and I have an error relating to Google API (`MissingKeyMapError` to be specific).

Following tips from the internet I have generated an API key but I cannot see where to enter the API key - in my index.html file or script.js? If you would would like to see the websites please let me know and I will share the URL's.

I've spent two days solid trying to fix this and can't see how to resolve.

I hope I have been specific enough.
I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#specify-a-key-when-loading-the-api

Comment: Thanks for the link. As I said generating the API isn't a problem but I can't see where to insert it.

When I enter it into the <head> it then tells me there are multiple versions of the API.

Comment: What does your code look like? Maybe look at some of the examples in the documentation?

Comment: Here are the URL's: http://www.mcscreative.co.uk/rdwright and http://www.rdwrightwc.co.uk

Comment: Which one works?  Which one doesn't?  Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself** not (just) a link to an external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key goes in this line:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(and you can remove the `sensor=false`)

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, my knowledge on JavaScript is poor. Where in the line exactly? Instead of the sensor=false?

Comment: Just tried replacing the sensor=false with my API code and still no luck. It works on the mcscreative domain but still not on rdwrightwc.

Comment: You need the "key=", see the example in my updated answer, replace YOUR_API_KEY with the correct value.

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank you very much!